# struct array pointer as a function parameter

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a data base structure to store info of employees

```
struct employeeData
{
   char name[50];
   int age;
   char rank[50];
   char level[50];
   char memo[100];
 };
```

After this, I have declared a pointer array such that

```
struct employeeData *eData[MAX];
```

in the main function.

Now, I have a function the following function...

```
 void newEmployee(struct employeeData *eData[MAX])
    {
      prinf("name: ");
    
      scanf("%s", eData[Database] -> name);
    
      printf("%s", eData[Database] -> name);
    }
```

It compiles with any errors and when I run it, I get to enter the name of the employee but t gives me a segmentation error right after.

What is my issue here?

I thought I used the pointer structure correctly in the newEmployee function.

Comment: The code you posted will not compile: there is a type specification missing for the function's argument. Assuming that is a pointer to one of your structures, you will need `struct employeeData *eData` as the argument list. Also, why have an array of pointers? Each will need to be allocated (using `malloc`) before use; better to have an array of structures.

Comment: you are right. Sorry, I missed that part. About using malloc, better to have an array of structures? I am not sure where to initialize it.

Comment: You should define the array: struct employeeData eData[MAX]; and pass it as a pointer:  void newEmployee(Struct employeeData *eData)

Comment: `struct employeeData *eData[MAX];` is a pointer but has no memory allocated to it.

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the 3 syntax errors in your question.  The question is not self-contained so we can only guess as to what you doing wrong the code you are not showing us.  `scanf()` is not safe so using `fgets()` instead.  @PaulOgilvie probably guessed correctly that that you don't allocate memory for the structs for those pointers to point at.

Here's a working self-contained example that probably solves the problem using the idea that @ImanH suggested:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct employeeData {
    char name[50];
    int age;
    char rank[50];
    char level[50];
    char memo[100];
};

void newEmployee(size_t n, struct employeeData eData[n]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("name: ");
        fgets(eData[i].name, sizeof(((struct employeeData *) 0)->name), stdin);     
        printf("%s", eData[i].name);
    }
}

int main() {
    struct employeeData e[2];
    newEmployee(sizeof(e) / sizeof(*e), e);
    return 0;
}
```

And if you want to use your array of pointers you could do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct employeeData {
    char name[50];
    int age;
    char rank[50];
    char level[50];
    char memo[100];
};

void newEmployee(size_t n, struct employeeData *eData[n]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        eData[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct employeeData));
        if(!eData[i]) {
            printf("malloc failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("name: ");
        fgets(eData[i]->name, sizeof(((struct employeeData *) 0)->name), stdin);
        printf("%s", eData[i]->name);
    }
}

int main() {
    struct employeeData *e[2] = {0};
    newEmployee(sizeof(e) / sizeof(*e), e);
    free(e[0]);
    free(e[1]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes, I noticed that scanf gives me some errors. So, I changed it to fgets and removed the last character of the string. I managed to learn malloc to use in this case. Thank you

Comment: I upvoted! Thank you for your help and also where can I accept the answer?